# Bandwidth control in linux

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, bandwidth

How do I control both the inbound and outbound bandwidth in a RHEL 5 router?

Answer (score 8):

`tc` (traffic control), from the [iproute2](http://www.linux-foundation.org/en/Net%3aIproute2) suite.

See the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/) – notably, the [queuing section](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html) – and [netem](http://www.linux-foundation.org/en/Net%3aNetem) for help.